# Write a java program to read from a lengthy string (using streams) and write the output to a file?

Tags: java, stream

How can I get a lengthy String as an input using streams and how to write the output to a file ?

Comment: Why are you using a string at all? If you've got an `InputStream` you can simply copy that to a `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: Use BufferedReader for reading and BufferedWriter for writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/*

Here is another way you can perform the storage.
```

*/

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WriteExample {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    FileOutputStream fop = null;
    File file;
    String content = "This is the text content";//our you can take it

    try {

        file = new File("c:/newfile.txt");//File creation at C:/
        fop = new FileOutputStream(file);

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        // get the content in bytes
        byte[] contentInBytes = content.getBytes();

        fop.write(contentInBytes);
        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
   finally{
      if(fop!=null){
      fop.flush();
      fop.close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can read from a string and write it on output file and how you can read from a input file and write it on output file .

char stream to byte stream conversion and vice versa is also mentioned

```
package task;

import java.io.*;


//char -> byte (input - byte , output - char);
//byte -> char (input - char , output - byte);

// 1.You have to use OutputStreamWriter class for converting Character stream to Byte stream. 
// 2.InputStreamReader class for converting Byte stream to Character stream, 
// as these classes are used for stream conversions between two different streams.

public class Ques1{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        //byte stream
         FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("input.txt");       
         //FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");


        //char stream 
        //FileReader in = new FileReader("input.txt");       
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter("output.txt");

        
        try{
            String s = "answet";
            int i = 0;
            while(i<s.length()){
                out.write(s.charAt(i));
                i++;
            }

            
            int t;
            // while((t=(in.read()))!=-1){
            //     out.write(t);
            // }
        }
        finally{
            if(in!=null) in.close();
            if(out!=null) out.close();
        }
    }
}
```